# Annotated Timeline Flickers and Re-Zooms

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I have an Annotated Timeline that I would like to update in realtime (similar to how [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3aFB) does it). However, I am having trouble getting the chart to not flicker and not re-zoom when data is added.

I couldn't get the code to work in JSFiddle (I think because annotated timeline is flash based?) but here is some basic code that you can plug in to [Google's Visualization Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line_configuration). You can see a [saved example here](http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=ffe1d224369fedabe64c18c30bc9301629d8bb33) but unfortunately can't modify the code, you'll have to go to the playground to do that.

```js
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'My Data');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,1), 30000],
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,2), 14045],
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,3), 55022],
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,4), 75284],
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,5), 41476],
    [new Date(2009, 1 ,6), 33322]
  ]);

  var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));

  var options = {
     'allowRedraw' : true ,
     'displayAnnotations' : true,
     'zoomStartTime': new Date(2009, 1 ,2), 
     'zoomEndTime': new Date(2009, 1 ,10)
  };
  annotatedtimeline.draw(data, options);

  // let's add some more data in 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
      again(annotatedtimeline, data, options);
  }, 3000);
}


function again(timeline, data, options) {
    data.addRow([new Date(2009, 1 ,7), 30000]);
    timeline.draw(data, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);​
```

What's weird is that I get pretty different flicker behavior depending on how I set displayAnnotations

`displayAnnotations = true` : Chart flickers but does not re-zoom
`displayAnnotations = false` : No chart flicker but it re-zooms to the new data (try it on the playground to see)

Setting `allowRedraw = false` causes the chart to flicker regardless. Any idea how to get no flicker and no re-zoom?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> - allowRedraw must be true
> - displayAnnotations must be false (that is, you cannot show annotations)

That's your problem.

Comment: So then why is the re-zoom happening?